# Meteor app deployed with Phusion Passenger shows error parsing app response chunked encoding: unexpected end-of-stream

Tags: nginx, meteor, passenger

I'm running a Meteor app deployed with Phusion Passenger and recently noticed that the app is intermittently dying and having problems restarting. It works most of the time, and I haven't updated it for a month or more. I assume my setup must be basically correct or it wouldn't work at all.

It seems to be something to do with chunking, unfortunately I don't know what that is or how to debug it.

I have tried `sudo service nginx restart` but the problem has recurred.

With Passenger log level 3 I saw this error:

```
phusion passenger Disconnecting client with error: error parsing app response chunked encoding: unexpected end-of-stream
```

Here is sample output from /var/log/nginx/error.log with Passenger log level set to 7:

`[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9223 20068/T5 Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:183 ]: [Client 103] ChunkedBodyParser: parsing new chunk
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9223 20068/T5 Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:123 ]: [Client 103] ChunkedBodyParser: chunk size determined: 78 bytes
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9224 20068/T5 Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:162 ]: [Client 103] ChunkedBodyParser: parsing 78 of 78 bytes of remaining chunk data; 0 now remaining
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9224 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:1415 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] Feeding 78 bytes
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9224 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:485 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] pushBuffer() completed: nbuffers = 1, bytesBuffered = 78
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9226 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:553 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] Reader: reading next
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9229 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:585 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] Reader: found buffer, 78 bytes
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9230 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:492 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] popBuffer() completed: nbuffers = 0, bytesBuffered = 0
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9230 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:593 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] Reader: feeding buffer, 78 bytes
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9230 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:553 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] Reader: reading next
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9230 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:560 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] Reader: no more buffers. Transitioning to RS_INACTIVE
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9230 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:538 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] Calling dataFlushedCallback
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9231 20068/T5 age/Cor/Con/ForwardResponse.cpp:64 ]: [Client 1-103] Event: onAppSourceData
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9231 20068/T5 age/Cor/Con/ForwardResponse.cpp:206 ]: [Client 1-103] Processing 7 bytes of application data: "\r\n0\r\n\r\n"
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9231 20068/T5 Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:248 ]: [Client 103] ChunkedBodyParser: done parsing a chunk
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9231 20068/T5 Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:183 ]: [Client 103] ChunkedBodyParser: parsing new chunk
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9231 20068/T5 Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:123 ]: [Client 103] ChunkedBodyParser: chunk size determined: 0 bytes
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9231 20068/T5 Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:162 ]: [Client 103] ChunkedBodyParser: parsing 0 of 0 bytes of remaining chunk data; 0 now remaining
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9231 20068/T5 Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:164 ]: [Client 103] ChunkedBodyParser: end chunk detected
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9232 20068/T5 Ser/HttpChunkedBodyParser.h:267 ]: [Client 103] ChunkedBodyParser: end chunk reached
[ D2 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9232 20068/T5 age/Cor/Con/ForwardResponse.cpp:224 ]: [Client 1-103] End of application response body reached
[ D2 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9232 20068/T5 age/Cor/Con/ForwardResponse.cpp:1105 ]: [Client 1-103] Not keep-aliving application session connection because application did not allow it
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9232 20068/T5 age/Cor/App/Socket.h:191 ]: Socket unix:/tmp/passenger.zqbz84I/apps.s/node.1gvzl3: connection not checked back into connection pool. There are$
[ D2 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9234 20068/T5 age/Cor/App/Gro/SessionManagement.cpp:150 ]: Session closed for process (pid=20096, group=/var/www/myapp/bundle/public)
[ D2 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9235 20068/T5 Ser/HttpServer.h:1185 ]: [Client 1-103] Ending request
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9239 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:1459 ]: [FBC 0x7f09bc018270] Deinitialize
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9240 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:1415 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] Feeding 0 bytes
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9240 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:485 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] pushBuffer() completed: nbuffers = 1, bytesBuffered = 0
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9240 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:553 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] Reader: reading next
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9240 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:565 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] Reader: EOF encountered. Feeding EOF
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9240 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:581 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] Reader: EOF fed. Transitioning to RS_TERMINATED
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9240 20068/T5 Ser/FileBufferedChannel.h:538 ]: [FBC 0xcb62f0] Calling dataFlushedCallback
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9241 20068/T5 Ser/HttpServer.h:278 ]: [Client 1-103] Request refcount decreased; it is now 1
[ D3 2018-03-19 10:53:01.9241 20068/T5 Ser/HttpServer.h:286 ]: [Client 1-103] Not keeping alive connection, disconnecting client`

My setup:

Passenger 5.1.12/nginx

Server is a Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu 16.04

App built with Meteor 1.6.0.1

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/

I am running 3 apps on this server, all built with the same version of Meteor and running under Passenger with no other apparent problems.

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing this problem and how it can be fixed?